# A suitable method to determine the value of multiple items based on their probability, and the cost of 'rolling the dice'?

Tags: probability

In a mobile game I play, Resources are acquired by playing 'stages'. Each stage has a Cost in order to acquire said resources, which have varying probabilities.

Say we have a set of Resources (A, B, C, D) which are obtained at differing rates from Stages 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Stage 1 offers a 110% chance of A, a 30% chance of B, a 4% chance of C, and a 1% chance of D, for a cost of 18.

Stage 2 offers a 60% chance of B, and a 1% chance of C, for a cost of 21.

Stage 3 offers a 20% chance of D, with a 10% chance of A, for a cost of 24.

Stage 4 has a flat 100% chance of obtaining B, for a cost of 24.

What I am looking to calculate is most accurate 'value' in terms of Cost of each of these Resources. My initial thought -- and what I have explored thus far -- is finding a Stage such a 4, which only offers a single resource, and using that as a 'base cost'. Then, I re-evaluate the cost of Resources each time I find a stage that is more efficient for that given resource; e.g. Stage 5 offers a 100% chance at B and a 10% chance at A, resulting in B's value being less than 24.

However, when reading about methodologies of discovering these values on Reddit, I realised that this may not necessarily be the most 'accurate' way of discerning the value of these resources.

Thus, my question is:
Is there a theory or method that is more suitable to solving this problem than what I have already described?

In the game proper, there are easily 100+ Stages, as well as many more Resources, if that has any impact on your answer. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: What do you mean stage 1 has 110% chance of A?  Do you always get at least one and get two 10% of the time?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at it backwards.  The resources have value based on what they can do for you, not on what it costs to acquire them.  If you can buy a \$1000 bill for \$1 and a \$100 bill for \$10, which is more valuable?

If the resources are fungible, so they can be exchanged into money and back at determined prices you can just compute the value of the production of each stage and compare to the investment required.  If the resources are not fungible, you need to assess what set of resources you need to accomplish your next objective, or assess the objectives that can be accomplished with the resources you have and the ones you can get from each stage.  If the game designers have done their job right, this is not simple.

If you can put a price on each resource, which may not be possible because the value of a resource to you may depend on what is scarce at the moment, you can compute an expected value of the return from each stage.  In that case you are only accumulating money, so you can find the stage with the highest return as long as you are playing enough for the law of averages to be valid.

You have not given enough information to make a more detailed answer.